# Where are the values of variables marked as 'dynamic' stored?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, dynamic, value-type, reference-type

On .net, value types are stored on the stack and reference types on the heap (and it's reference on the stack).

But if a variable is marked as `dynamic`, is this rule still valid based on the run-time type of the data?

I was looking for some reference that points to this, but didn't find any.

Comment: “value types are stored on the stack and reference types on the heap” That's simply wrong. Value types can be stored on the heap too. And of course there are also registers. And some instances of reference types *could* be stored on the stack, as an optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable of type *dynamic* is a System.Object at runtime.  So it is always a reference to an object that's stored on the GC heap.  If you assign a value type value to the variable then it will be boxed with a standard boxing conversion.